# How to filter an array using two parameters?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have a program that adds or removes cars to an array called `pile` so that the cars can later be selected based on filters and criteria.  The code works as it is but I am trying to increase it's efficiency for later changes.  Below is code to show what my question is:

```
if ( var1 == true ) {
  pile.push(car1);
} else if ( var1 == false ) {
  pile = pile.filter( removeCar );
}

function removeCar(elem) {
  return String(elem[0][0]) !== 'Jeep';
}
```

What I want to do is for `removeCar()` to have two parameters so it is `removeCar(elem, make)` such that if `make` = 'Jeep' the code would function the same way. Unfortunately, as you can see `removeCar` is called by `filter` with no parameters and elem is automatically assigned to the current element.

How can I add parameters to the `.filter( removeCar)`?

Comment: interesting, you assign `true` to the variables and do not make a check with it.

Comment: I don't think this code works. `If(var1 = true)` will always be true because thats assignment and you will never get to the else. Also in the else you don't need to test if its false again because if it's not true it will be false assuming that its a boolean ofcourse. Now you can pass in values in to a function by so    `pile = pile.filter( elem => removeCar(elem) );`

Comment: yea I just didn't copy that part correctly because it is more complicated and hides the meaning of the question which is about the filter part. the question is fixed.

Comment: Okay great, that fixes it. In JS when checking for equality though it's always good to use three `===` but this would work

Comment: @Nsoseka technically you gave me the correct answer first but as a comment, but Dima posted the correct answer as an answer, so if you add your comment as an answer I'll mark it as the solution but if not I'll just mark Dimas

Comment: let me make it an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include parameters in the filter if you structure the statement differently:
`pile = pile.filter( elem => removeCar(elem, make) );`

Answer (score 1):

```
pile = pile.filter( x => removeCar(x) );
```

Try this. If `removeCar(x)` return true, x(current element of pile) will be added to new pile array

And in your if/else must be '==' or '===' not '='

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
if (var1) pile.push(car1);
pile = filterPile(pile, make);

function filterPile(pile, make){
 if(!pile) pile;
 return pile.filter(val=> val[0][0].toString() !== make)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define custom filter functions by wrapping the native [Array filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method:

```js
// A custom filter function which accepts a 'pile' and a 'make' parameter.
function removeFromPileByMake(pile, make) {
    // Assuming every element holds an object at [0]
    return pile.filter(elem => elem[0][0] !== make);
}

var make = 'Jeep';

if ( var1 ) {
    pile.push(car1);
} else {
    pile = removeFromPileByMake(pile, make);
}
```